# Why is Hal Jordan considered an idiot and when did such a depiction begin?

Tags: dc, comics, green-lantern

I'm not the deepest DC comics reader, but I read a few growing up in the 70's and 80's. Also, watching most seasons of the *Superfriends* cartoon at the time, I got the impression that Hal Jordan (Green Lantern) was the most authoritative/wise figure in the Justice League (beyond even Batman or Superman).

Then when I started paying attention to online discussions in the 2000's or so, I started seeing "everyone knows Hal Jordan is an idiot"-type comments, but I never saw any reason or justification for that. It seems to be at odds with his fighter-pilot, need-to-be-focused, willpower-dependent super powers. I'm still curious about that.

Here are a few current examples:

- [Hal Jordan is a Big Dumb Idiot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSbBQ.jpg) site on Imgur
- [Hal Jordan is an Idiot](https://archiveofourown.org/tags/Hal%20Jordan%20Is%20An%20Idiot) tag on Archive of Our Own
- [Hal Jordan: Canon Idiot](https://www.reddit.com/r/comicbooks/comments/2xbqgf/hal_jordan_canon_idiot_green_lantern_in_emerald/) on Reddit
- [Hal Jordan is an Idiot](https://www.tumblr.com/search/hal+jordan+is+an+idiot) tag on Tumblr
- [Hal is Dumb](https://www.tumblr.com/search/hal%20is%20dumb) tag on Tumblr

So: What justification is there for Hal Jordan to be considered an obvious idiot? What is the earliest instance of this legacy? Examples from the 70's/80's or earlier preferred.

Comment: That's a bit unclear unless you provide in-context examples of him being called a dummy. It's also unclear/opinion-based what "stupid" means here: Hal _ does_ rush more hastily into a fight than, say, John Stewart, but I wouldn't say that's dumb. So please edit the question to clarify - maybe it's just me but I've never thought of him as dumb, or seen him widely called so. Now Guy Gardner on the other hand...

Comment: The canon example that comes to my mind is the first New 52 _Justice League_ arc, where he accidentally calls the Flash "Barry" while chiding him for revealing some minor detail of his (Flash's) own secret identity. That whole storyline had a lot of dumping on Hal, honestly. It seemed like "Hal's an arrogant blowhard" was supposed to be the status quo, though perhaps they made him more mature after that arc ended and they jumped ahead a few years.